# How to parse "0.0000e+000" into a float/double?

Tags: c#, .net

I tried the following:

```
string val = "0.0000e+000";
float.Parse(val);
```

...yet got a `FormatException`. So I wonder: how to parse such a value into a float/double?

[image: Parsing into a float]

[image: Parsing into a double]

Comment: The code `var x = Single.Parse("0.0000e+000");` runs without throwing an exception in a new project.  Can you post more of your code in context?

Comment: `var d = Convert.ToDouble("0.0000e+000");` works too

Comment: Check your value. As @Cole commented, using the method with the value you have provided works. What is the value that causes the exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` (the current culture) for which the decimal dot is different. Try parsing it with the invariant culture instead:

```
var x = Single.Parse("0.0000e+000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

To illustrate the problem: if you were Russian, your current culture would be set to `ru-RU`. And then the following *fails*:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
var x = Single.Parse("0.0000e+000");
```

> **FormatException**: Input string was not in a correct format.

If you are French (`fr-FR`), it will fail too. It will probably fail for some other cultures too.

Comment: I think the current culture is set to `ru-RU` because the exception itself is talking about a wrong format (формат). Good point!

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic That was only a guess, because the exception looked Russian to me. The same problem happens in French, and probably a number of other languages.

Comment: Fyi: входная строка имела неверный формат = The given input string has a wrong format.  Learning Russian with C# :D

Comment: An app we have on the store was throwing this error. Weirdly all the users giving this feedback about this crash were from Russia/France. Took a while to make the connection.